# JQuery para trocar <small>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perguntinha rápida que não achei em lugar algum..

Como troco o texto de um small?

Estou tentando com o mesmo código que usei pra trocar um texto uma vez, 
acho que o problema está nos seletores, mas já testei com todos eles e não rolou. Não tenho acesso ao HTML e a versão do Jq é 1.12.4
JQ:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('td[name=Boleto]')
    .find('small')
    .text('Transferência');
});
```

html:

```
<label class="card Billet">
   <input type="radio" value="Billet" class="rdoCreditCards" name="CreditCardProvider" id="CreditCardProvider" displayname="Boleto">
   <span>
      <small>Boleto</small>
   </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Ficou confuso esse `td[name=Boleto]` visto que nem tem o elemento `<td>` no seu código.

Comment: Você está selecionando um elemento que não existe na sua pergunta `td`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, exato...

Comment: Viajei.. Vou corrigir.. haha

Comment: O resto tá certo então?

Comment: Se vc tiver uma tag `small` dentro de um `td` com o name `Boleto`, ficaria assim:  `$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('td[name="Boleto"]')
    .find('small')
    .text('Transferência');
});`

Comment: Não é um td, é uma label dentro de uma div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** foi adicionado no jQuery a partir da versão 1.7. Provavelmente seu código está dando o erro `$(...).on is not a function`, já que diz estar usando a versão 1.12.4.

Nessa versão você teria que usar o método `.load()`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

E para alterar o texto, seu código está quase correto, basta alterar o seletor para a `div` onde está o `small`. Por exemplo:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('div')
    .find('small')
    .text('Transferência');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label class="card Billet">
      <input type="radio" value="Billet" class="rdoCreditCards" name="CreditCardProvider" id="CreditCardProvider" displayname="Boleto">
      <span>
         <small>Boleto</small>
      </span>
   </label>
</div>
```